# c++ change print format from integer 2255 to $xx.xx

Tags: c++

I have function return int i = 2255 which mean how many cents in my pocket and I want to print it in $xx.xx format
how do I print this one to 22.55? Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried doing it yourself? If so, show us.

Comment: Isn't this taught really early in school, about moving the decimal point when multiplying / dividing by 10s, 100s etc

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("$%d.%d", i / 100, i % 100);
```

or

```
printf("$%0.2f", double(i) / 100);
```

Though, in C++11 and later, consider using `std::cout` with [`std::put_money()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_money) instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

std::cout << std::put_money(double(i) / 100);
```

Answer (score -1):

One way is to setup the `cout` stream to print the format you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    int i = 2250;

    std::cout << std::fixed;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
    std::cout << i/100.0 << std::endl;  // Divide by 100.00 to convert to double

    return 0;
}
```